# R: Ggplot2 Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (72): fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gis

I am trying to creat a ggplot for the population by county for Wisconsin

```
library(broom)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rayshader)
library(viridis)
library(tidyverse)

#Population CSV
population = read_csv("co-est2019-annres-55.csv")

#Import Shapefile
Wi_counties <- st_read(
  "County_Boundaries_24K.shp")

#Plot Shapefile
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = Wi_counties, size = 1, color = "black", fill = "cyan1") + 
  ggtitle("WI_Counties") + 
  coord_sf()

gg_wi = ggplot(Wi_counties) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = population)) +
  scale_fill_viridis("population") +
  ggtitle("Population by County in Wisconsin") +
  theme_bw()

plot_gg(gg_wi, multicore = TRUE, width = 6 ,height=2.7, fov = 70)
```

But am getting this error:
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (72): fill

Data Here
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8zjwt55yg4x1o2h/AADBDuTcIhym9tlrx9JkfVhoa?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You map a dataframe (`population`) on `fill`
2. As your data has no header you have to set `col_names = FALSE` in `read_csv`
3. You have to join the shapefile and your dataframe with the `population` data. Otherweise it is not guarenteed that you the population sizes are mapped to the right county.
4. Even when solving these problems `plot_gg` throws an error `Error in if (whichtype %in% c("text", "line")) { :  argument is of length zero` related to `theme_bw`. For a solution to this last issue see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61263862/rayshader-plot-gg-crashes-while-running-example).

To solve the first three issues use `col_names = FALSE` or name the cols as I do in my code below. Second. Get rid of the added `County` in the county names. Third. Join the shapefile and the population data by county. Fourth, map the population size on `fill`. Try this:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
library(readr)
library(rayshader)
library(dplyr)

#Population CSV
population = read_csv(here::here("Wisconsin/co-est2019-annres-55.csv"), col_names = c("county", "pop")) %>% 
  mutate(county = gsub("\\sCounty", "", county))
  
#Import Shapefile
Wi_counties <- st_read(here::here("Wisconsin/County_Boundaries_24K.shp"))

Wi_counties_join <- Wi_counties %>% 
  left_join(population, by = c("COUNTY_NAM" = "county"))

#Plot Shapefile
gg_wi = ggplot(Wi_counties_join) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = pop)) +
  scale_fill_viridis("population") +
  ggtitle("Population by County in Wisconsin") +
  theme_bw()
gg_wi

#plot_gg(gg_wi, multicore = TRUE, width = 6 ,height=2.7, fov = 70)
```

[image]

Comment: @JacobBenzaquen Hm. When I read the population data on my machine the population size is read as a numeric. However, from the error message I would guess that the population sizes are not numeric. Check the datatypes e.g. using `str(population)`. If pop is of type `chr` you have to convert it to a numeric.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you convert your population data into a numeric column and join it to your shapefile.
This code worked for me:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(rayshader)
library(viridis)

#Population CSV
population <- read.csv("Wisconsin_Population/co-est2019-annres-55.csv")

#new column COUNTY_NAM matching the county names from shapefile
population$COUNTY_NAM <- substr(as.character(population$V1), 1, nchar(as.character(population$V1))-7)

#convert V2 into numeric column
population$V2 <- as.numeric(population$V2)

#Import Shapefile
Wi_counties <- st_read("Wisconsin_Population/County_Boundaries_24K.shp")

#perform left_join with population data
Wi_counties <- Wi_counties %>% left_join(population, by = c("COUNTY_NAM"))

#Plot Shapefile
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = Wi_counties, size = 1, color = "black", fill = "cyan1") + 
  ggtitle("WI_Counties") + 
  coord_sf()

gg_wi <- ggplot(Wi_counties) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = V2)) +
  scale_fill_viridis() +
  ggtitle("Population by County in Wisconsin") +
  theme_bw()

plot_gg(gg_wi, multicore = TRUE, width = 6, height=2.7, fov = 70)
```

Comment: I get this error                                                                                                                       #new column COUNTY_NAM matching the county names from shapefile
population$COUNTY_NAM <- substr(as.character(population$V1), 1, nchar(as.character(population$V1))-7)                                                                            Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, COUNTY_NAM, value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 71